# Media query responsive table design not responding to mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I expect each table row to fill to a maximum of 600px, but a table row to be 100% of the screen width when the viewport is less than 600px.   There seems to be no response in Chrome Developer Tools given a small viewport.  Why?

```html
<style>

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    
 table,tr,td {
  width:100%;
  margin:0 0;
 }
 
}

</style>

<table style="max-width:600px;margin:0 auto;width:100%" align="center">
 
  <tr class="test">
   <td style="background-color:red;text-align:center" class="test">
   To view this email as a web page, click <a href="http://cl.exct.net/?qs=fa9cfc6a348d126dc3bf79e0967a225ce97afcb944f78d7e6044adc134e725b0">here.</a>

   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="test">
   <td style="background-color:blue;text-align:left" class="test">
   test2
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="test">
   <td class="test">
    <div>
    <img src="http://image.exct.net/lib/fec315777067017a/m/1/share_twitter.jpg" align="right">
    <img src="http://image.exct.net/lib/fec315777067017a/m/1/share_facebook.gif" align="right">
    </div>
   </td>
   
  </tr>
 
</table>
```

--Update--

The code above works on Outlook Mobile, works when resizing Chrome window to less than 600px, works in FireFox on resize and in developer mode, works in IE on resize, but does not work in Chrome Developer Console with an emulated device less than 600px wide, and does not work on my Android Nexus 6.

Comment: working here on FF...

Comment: Worked for me in Chrome.

Comment: It works on FireFox.  It does not work on Chrome Developer Console or on my Android Nexus 6.

Comment: Try adding `table,tr,td {display:block;}` into your media query.

Comment: adding display:block did not work.

Comment: For mobile devices add [meta viewport width](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) `width=device-width`.

Comment: Just a side note: It looks like you're trying to use this for a mail. Mail clients can be really bitchy and support for some features is terrible. I'm not sure using media-queries in a mail is such a brilliant idea.

Comment: We have a nice support for media queries in html emails nowadays, please do not discourage him. Things are changing to better.

Comment: I understand @mmgross but the media query is working on mobile clients, but I want the user to be able to click the link and view as a webpage on a mobile device shuold there be issues - the main purpose of the media query.

Comment: Please add meta viewport in html, that's your only problem.

Comment: Works, please post this as solution @skobaljic

Comment: @skobaljic Thanks for the info. I guess I need to update my knowledge a bit. Does this apply to gmail as well?

Comment: @mmgross check [Campaign Monitor's CSS Guide](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for CSS styling compatibility

Comment: Thanks, but that's from 2014 and says that only Apple supports responsive html-mails

Comment: @mmgross, think gmail still strips style tags, also the gmail app on mobile phones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding tag

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

resolves this issue.

Comment: Nailed it. Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

When you're using inline styles like:

```
<table style="max-width:600px;margin:0 auto;width:100%" align="center">
```

In your HTML you're going to have to override it by adding `!important` to your css.

Here's your code working in JSfiddle. The only thing that I changed was adding that `!important` tag to your css!

https://jsfiddle.net/pLtb28a1/

Keep in mind that the only way to override a tag with the `!important` flag on it is to use another `!important` flag on your override. They can make things a little tricky if you forget you are using them.

Comment: Although it's inline, the actual styles he uses won't override anything in the CSS file in a negative way.

Comment: Removing !important  within this jsfiddle still yields expected results, so this is not the solution.

Comment: It looks like you're correct! Oops, your answer seems to be the right one!